# Generate a longest bit sequence where all 5-bits consecutive sub sequence are unique

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bit-manipulation

Generate a longest bit sequence (only 0 or 1 for every slot).

In this sequence, all consecutive `m-bit` sub sequences are distinct.

For example, if m = 2, then `00110` is such a longest sequence. All 2-bit sub-sequences are unique: `00` `01` `11` `10`.

---

Using brute-force we can surely find such a sequence for a `m`.

However, is there a clever way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the solution in: *Invitation to Discrete Mathematics* by Matousek and Nesetril page 140 (btw. one of the most beautiful books on the subject).

The answer is surprisingly: 2<sup>k</sup> for each k >= 1 (in your case 32).
I will cite:

> Define a graph G = (V,E) in the following manner: (%) V is the set of all sequences of 0s and 1s of length k - 1 (%) The directed edges are all pairs of (k-1)-digit sequences of the form ((a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>k-1</sub>),(a<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>k</sub>)). Directed edges are in a bijective correspondence with k-digit sequences (a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>k</sub>).

And then it is enough to find an Eulerian tour in G.

---

**EDIT**
They treat the sequence as if it its end and start were *glued*. E.g. to get `00` from `0110` we start at the last digit and then the next digit is the first digit of the sequence.
So the 2<sup>k</sup>-sequence can be actually extended by appending the first (k-1) digits to the end.

Comment: Do you mean Hamiltonian rather than Eulerian path?

Comment: @Anonymous: No, he means Eulerian.  You're allowed to visit the same vertex more than once because a vertex does not represent a k-digit sequence -- only an edge leaving a vertex does.

Comment: @Anonymous j_random_hacker is right [I recommend to check it directly in the book]

Comment: Thanks, got it! The answer should be 2^k+k-1 though I think, since we're producing a sequence of bits. Eg: k=2 gives 00110, which has length 5, not 4.

Comment: @Anonymous yes you are completely right. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a [De Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).

There seems to have been a lot of research on these, but unfortunately the results are mostly [stuck](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-19094-0_19) [behind](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0920548908001657) [paywalls](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/565596)

I did find [one paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/messages/downloadsexceeded.html) available online.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use arithmetic in Galois Field.

Starting with a polynomial `P_0(x) = 0*x^4 + 0*x^3 + 0*x^2 + 0*x^1 + 1` == 0b00001, we can compute the next element `P_1(x) = P_0(x) * x mod R(x)`, where R(x) must be a primitive polynomial in GF(2^5).

What follows is a sequence of length 2^5 - 1, where each bit position goes through most of the unique subsequences -- except the sequence 0b00000.

This can be easily fixed by starting with a zero, and appending the MSB term of each polynomial P_i(x).

```
 void linear_feedback_shift_register() {
     uint8_t poly = 0b00001;
     // start with an extra zero, otherwise we can't have '00000'
     std::cout << "0" << (poly >> 4);
     for (int i = 0; i < 32+2; i++) {
         poly <<= 1;
         if (poly & 0b100000) {
             poly ^= 0b100101; // 1+x^2+x^5 is a primitive polynomial
         }
         std::cout << (poly >> 4);
     }
     std::cout << "\n";
 }
```

Output:

```
 000001001011001111100011011101010000
```

(Total 36 characters printed, with all 32 subsequences of 5)